Can someone prove $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\frac{1}{n}\int_{na}^{nb} f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\,dx\ $?
Question:
Hi everyone,
I was working on a problem and came across the idea that the integral of a function $f(x)$ from $a$ to $ b $ can be equal to the integral of the function $ f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) $ from $na$ to $ nb$, scaled by a factor of $\frac{1}{n}$.
Specifically, it looks like this:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\frac{1}{n}\int_{na}^{nb} f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\,dx.$$
where $ n \in \mathbb{R}$  and $x \in \mathbb{R} .$
This seems clear if we perform the change of variable $x = nu$ However, after doing so, we end up with the integral in terms of $u$, which makes me unsure whether the equality holds as stated.
Can someone proof this rigorously?
I apologize if this is a basic question—I'm just starting out in this field. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Are you suggesting that $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(x),\mathrm dx$ might be different from $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(u),\mathrm du$?

You can always replace the free variable in integration with some other letter.

Let's say we end up with two integrals. First is
$$\int\limits_{x=a}^{b} f(x)dx$$
and second is
$$\int\limits_{u=a}^{b}f(u)du$$
Notice that we've remembered our differentials, so we've got stuff with a $du$ instead of another $dx$. These are definite integrals, so they're just numbers, like 3 or 7. For the first one, we end up with $\left[F(x)\right]_{x=a}^{b}$, and for the second, since it's integrated with respect to $u$ and not $x$, we get $\left[F(u)\right]_{u=a}^{b}$
Both of these will end up as $F(b)-F(a)$, which is just a number.
This is the idea of a dummy variable. It doesn't matter what symbol we use. If it's the same function with the same bounds, it's the same number.
$$\int\limits_{x=a}^{b}f(x)dx=\\
\int\limits_{u=a}^{b}f(u)du=\\
\int\limits_{t=a}^{b}f(t)dt=\\
\int\limits_{\text{中国}=a}^{b}f(\text{中国})d\text{中国}=
F(b)-F(a)$$

Technically speaking, the sequence of two Unicode characters might be misunderstood as the product of two varaibles.

Yes, good point. It was simply an extreme example to demonstrate that the way we represent the variable isn't really impactful.
